# jQuery UI Drag/Drop - Overflow, position fixed - FireFox drop not firing

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, draggable

I am building my system and I wanted to use jQuery UI, but I am experiencing some trouble with FF, it works fine with IE and Chrome no problem, and as these are the two main browsers used by the company, it is not urgent, but as I use jQuery UI a lot on other projects, and it's an interesting little quirk (maybe a bug?), it needs mentioning.
I want to assign two database table to another and insert the assignment into another table.

```
<div id="to" style="width:100px;">
    <table border="1">
       <tr class="tableHeader">
          <td>Employee</td>
      </tr>

            <tr><td>...</td></tr>

       </table>
</div>
<div id="from" style="height:8em">
    <table>
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
and JS:
$('#from tr').draggable({ 
    revert: "invalid", appendTo : "#content", helper : "clone" });

$('#to').droppable({drop : function(event, ui) {
        alert("Drop")
    }});
```

Please see my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vS3EH/) to demonstrate, if you're using FF, you will notice that when you drag a record from near the bottom of the "from" table, the div scrollbar will snap back to the top, and the helper is displayed a way down from the Y of the mouse, meaning that you can't drop the record as it is too far down.

As I said, no problem in IE or Chrome, and that's what my client use, but isn't it funny?

Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hei Luke,

Try to add `cursorAt: { bottom: 0 }` in your draggable function. It should work in FF.

```
 $('#from tr').draggable({ 
    revert: "invalid",     
    cursorAt: { bottom: 0 }, 
    appendTo : "#content", 
    helper : "clone" 
 });
```

Update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vS3EH/11/

Comment: Thank you that solved it. There is still an issue with the helper being displayed in the right location, but I can't seem to recreate the issue, I have many employee groups, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vS3EH/12/ . But the drop event works, and that's the important thing